# Recover m3 instance with AWS Cloudwatch Alarm

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cloudwatch

I'm trying to setup a CloudWatch Alarm that automatically recover my instance if it goes down.

The problem is that CloudWatch allows me to automatically send an email but it doesn't let me check the Recover instance button.

Given the following documentation: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatch/latest/DeveloperGuide/UsingAlarmActions.html

I've checked that:
- My instance is m3.xlarge
- My instance is located on EU-Ireland
- My instance is VPC
- My instance tenancy property is set to default
- My instance uses EBS exclusively (root device type set to EBS)

Does anyone know why it doesn't allow me to add a "Recover this instance" to the CloudWatch Alarm?

Comment: I had faced unexplainable weird behaviour with AWS Console which were resolved by using a different browser. Beside, try setting up the alarm using AWS-CLI instead of AWS console. See if that works.

Comment: Tried with another two browsers but it still doesn't work. Really weird problem. :-/

Comment: Did you get this to work? I am having the same problem. Can't get it to work.

Comment: Sorry @SambhavSharma I was not able to make it work

Answer (score 0):

I realize this answer is late, but incase anyone else has this issue:

The issue is probably that you are using the internal ephemeral instance store volumes, in addition to EBS volumes. AWS does not support that for instance recovery. You have to use only EBS volumes and then it will work. For full details and troubleshooting, see the AWS documentation: https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/recover-this-instance-cloudwatch-enable/

-tom

Comment: Hi, thank you for the try. I've checked it twice and I don't have ephemeral store volumes. Just one big EBS volume.

Comment: Weird if you tried everything in the AWS link. Perhaps you should try creating an AMI from your current image and then launchie a fresh Ec2 from it and see if it is then enabled.